# InternalsVisibleTo using the "Company" property instead of "Assembly Name"?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Is it possible to make the internal functionality of a common utility library available for usage by all assemblies with my company name so that future assemblies can also use the same version?

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("The Company Name Instead")]
```

Comment: No. It is not possible. `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` must be applied on an assembly-by-assembly basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Specifies that types that are ordinarily visible only within the current assembly are visible to a specified assembly.

The attribute is also sealed so you can't extend it to attempt to implement your own functionality.

It doesn't even support wildcards.

I don't know what the actual problem is you're trying to solve but you may want to reconsider why you need internals visible to, to begin with.

Maybe the utility library can be merged into your assembly using internalize so that you don't have a utility assembly laying around.

Comment: Thanks :)

I am working on plugins for the Unity game engine which all get stuck into the same project. I have common functionality for my plugins which should not be exposed to the end user.

I could merge the common assembly into each of the plugins but I suspect that I will need some trickery to auto rename namespaces unique to avoid conflicts.

With each new plugin I will have to release an update for all of my others so that the common assembly has all the `InternalsVisibleTo`'s. The common assembly will get overwritten by Unity when another plugin is imported that also includes it.

Comment: If you merge with internalize, you wont get namespace conflicts. Lots of projects do it. RavenDB does it with JSON.NET so that people referencing JSON.Net don't get conflicts.

Comment: Interesting; so if I merge the common library into plugin A and plugin B, and both plugins are loaded into Unity, then A & B wont be colliding? I'll have to give that a go! thanks :)

Comment: Correct. Internalize is an awesome feature :)